# Determine class in init method

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, foundation

I have a global dictionary with `Class` objects and `NSString` keys. Every custom subclass of my `Property` class can register itself on the `Property` superclass using

```
+ (void)registerPropertyClass:(Class)pclass forNamePrefix:(NSString *)namePrefix
```

A `Property` is initialized with a `name` and `value`. What I want to do now is return a different class from the init method based on the `name` prefix (if a registered class matches).

Would something like this be correct?

```
- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)name value:(NSString *)value
  id instance = self;

  NSArray *registeredPrefixes = [kCKPropertyClasses allKeys];
  for (NSString *prefix in registeredPrefixes) {
    if ([name rangeOfString:prefix].location == 0) {
      instance = [[kCKPropertyClasses objectForKey:prefix] alloc];
      break;
    }
  }

  self = [instance init];
  if (self) {
    self.name = name;
    self.value = value;
  }
  return self;
}
```

UPDATE: Forgot to mention that this project is using ARC (so no retain/release)

Comment: I suggest changing the loop to only obtain the class, and move the `alloc` to the same statement as `init`. It's always best to keep `alloc` and `init` paired together. And since you're using ARC, you may want to replace the `alloc` and `init` pair with `new`. Finally, getting `allKeys` isn't necessary; you can iterate on the dictionary directly, and it will yield its keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without compiling it, that'll work, but leak under manual-retain-release.  You need to `release` `self` prior to the reassignment `self = [instance init];`.

With ARC, it should be fine.